# Fade In at Div and Fade Out away from Div

Tags: html, callback, fadein, fadeout

I've got a scroll path event occurring when I reach this point in the site's destination. As you can see from the following code, when a user travels to this specific point, "my work," the div "#mywork" fades in, (as it's css is originally set to display:hidden.)

```
path.lineTo( 3220, 4600,{
callback: function() {
    $("#mywork").fadeIn(2000, "linear");}, name: "mywork"});
```

I would like the "#mywork" div to fade out whenever the user leaves this point (i.e. scrolls away from it, and/or clicks on a different navigation link.) If the user returns, I would like for the div to fade back into view as it normally would.

Any suggestions? Thanks so much in advance if you can find the time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this library can help you out. You'd use it in place of path.lineTo.

https://github.com/sakabako/scrollMonitor

Comment: Thanks. For a newbie such as myself, would you care to help explain how I could apply scrollMonitor to fading in/out my div upon enter/exit?

Comment: Include the scrollMonitor javascript file then you can use the example in the readme (without the first line) almost verbatim.